# Sql Server 2008 R2 Primary Key Clustered index

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index

I have a sql database with some small tables and has PK clustered indexes on it. My question is: Is it going to be a concern if the PK indexes isn't being used? And that isn't accessed very often? Please help, thanks

Comment: your question is not clear. You may want to rewrite your question. What do you mean by PK indexes not being used?

Comment: Primary Key Clustered Indexes